# Executing task scheduler remotely via batch file is fine but not when compiling the same batch file to IEXPRESS executable

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

Im trying to run a scheduled task on 2012 server (64bit)  remotely from a Win 7 client (32bit) via a batch job.

The batch job command as follows:

```
schtasks /Run /S tXXXX /U Administrator /P XXXXX /TN dataprint
```

The batch job is able to execute successfully from Win 7 client, and triggered the task scheduler.

However, after i compiled the batch to exe using Win7 iexpress, the task was not triggered with no error.

Ive also tried to create the exe from the server's IEXPRESS (32 bit). Mapped drive to the server's folder and execute the exe file. It's also cannot triggered the task scheduler.

What could be the cause?